# Recyclerview get item by screen position x/y

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it somehow possible to get an item of a recyclerview at a specific screen position (x and y coordinate)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get `View` of an item at specific coordinates with this method [findChildViewUnder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#findchildviewunder).

```
View itemView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
```